# Whats the origin of Harem genre

Tags: anime-history, manga-history

[image]

Harem is genre in Anime and Manga involving a Male protagonist surrounded by girls who have feelings for him

Harem is a popular genre in the anime/manga industry but what are the origins of how it become one of Anime and Mangas popular genres?

Comment: Hmm... Could it be [harems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harem)?

Comment: What Gallifreyan said. A long time ago, Men went to war and died, leaving an imbalance. As well, the more wives you had, the more desierable you seemed/felt to women in general. It was a sign of power and wealth. I bet there is also a correlation between it and the viewers, many of whom tend to be single or generally undesirable to women. Some Superfans even refuse to marry "3d girls", to the point of wanting to marry the fictional characters of anime. What they lack, Harem Kings have.

Comment: @Ryan I actually asking which anime or manga popularised the genre

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/what-is-the-origin-of-harem-anime

Comment: https://myanimelist.net/anime/genre/35/Harem?page=4 From the oldest anime in MAL database, it seems like Love Hina is the most popular. I'd make an educated guess in favour of it.

Comment: @Arcane I would argue that Rumiko Takahashi's early work introduced a lot of the tropes used in modern day harem anime, while _Tenchi Muyo_ really defined what we think of today as the harem genre, though newer harem shows are heavily influenced by _Love Hina_. _To-Love-Ru_, for instance, is basically a _Love Hina_-ization of _Urusei Yatsura_, in the same way that _Love Hina_ itself was a _Love Hina_-ization of _Maison Ikkoku_.

Answer (score 6):

The first anime or manga to have all the elements of the harem genre is [Tenchi Muyo! Ryo-Ohki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenchi_Muyo!_Ryo-Ohki) (OVA anime: 1992). It has multiple female characters pursuing the same male lead, a constant presence in his life, in this case living with him in the same house. Like most examples of this genre the main character acquired his harem accidentally and doesn't actually want all these women pursuing him. Also like many examples of the genre the female characters are very extraordinary, far from ordinary Japanese girls.

You can see the origins of the genre in other manga and anime series that had many of the same tropes but never put them all together. For example [Oh My Goddess!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh_My_Goddess!) (manga: 1988, OVA anime: 1993) has three goddesses living in the same house with the main character, although only one is interested him romantically. [Ranma 1/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranma_%C2%BD) (manga: 1987, TV anime: 1989) has a main character with a number of different suitors over the course of the long series, both female and male, but they don't form a harem as most of these characters only make occasional appearances.

A likely influence of harem genre is the reverse harem genre.  While you'd think from its name the reverse harem genre came later, the trope of a woman with many suitors is probably old as storytelling. The [suitors of Penelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suitors_of_Penelope) in the [Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey) (ca. 700 BC) were 108 men who pursued Penelope, the wife of the presumed dead Odysseus, while all living together in his home. While the Odyssey probably wasn't a direct influence on the genre, shoujo romance series like [Fushigi Yuugi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fushigi_Y%C3%BBgi) (manga: 1992, TV anime: 1995) and [Hanasakeru Seishounen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanasakeru_Seish%C5%8Dnen) (manga: 1987, TV anime 2009) have pretty much all the elements you'd expect in the harem genre except with the male/female roles exchanged.

Another possible influence would be love triangles appearing various male oriented series like [Maison Ikkoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maison_Ikkoku) (manga: 1980, TV anime: 1986) and [Kimagure Orange Road](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimagure_Orange_Road) (manga: 1984, TV anime: 1987). Yet another possible influence are dating sim and ren'ai visual novel games were the player can pursue one or more of a number different love interests. While the structure is different, when these games get turned into anime shows they're often become harem anime.

As for why the harem genre is popular it's hard to say. The obvious answer is that it provides the stereotypical shy-with-women male otaku with a sort of escapism and wish fulfillment they can't get from other genres. However I don't think it would be as popular if it was just that. I think subverting the age old trope of a woman with many suitors is a big part. It provides a lot comedic potential in what in real life would seem absurd: a number of always attractive and usually exceptional women all openly pursing the same ordinary looking usually kind of awkward guy.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I want to pick up is [The tale of genji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_Genji)

The original novel was published on 1008.
[The manga version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tale_of_Genji_(manga)) was published on 1980.
[The anime version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genji_Monogatari_Sennenki) was aired on 2009 in noitaminA.